# [PHP]User complaining about logging in to prexisting accounts after facebook signup

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, web, web-frameworks

Today, I was informed that when a user signed up on my website with Facebook they were redirected to another user's account (if account exists they are redirected to login ) but their specific user account didn't exist so it should have spit out the error below. This is the first user to complain of this. 
The login script is fairly simple and straight forward. 
Does anyone see any issues with the logic of this code or could this be a Facebook issue?
I'm pretty stumped on this one as it seems to be working for all the other users.

Any help is MUCH appreciated.

Thank you.
Language is PHP and Code Igniter

here is the code..

```
 public function signin_fb_check(){
    $this->layout = FALSE;
    $this->template = FALSE;

    $check_exists_user = $this->User->row(array('conditions' => array_filter(array(               
            'email' => $this->ahrform->get('email')
        ))));

    if(count($check_exists_user)>0){

        $id = $check_exists_user->id;
        $userid = $check_exists_user->id;
        $this->ahruser->User('Login', $userid);
        $session_token = uniqid();
        $uinfo = array('token' => $session_token, 'userid' => $userid, 'user' => $check_exists_user);
        $this->ahrsession->set('LoginInfoFront', $uinfo);

        //if($check_exists_user->project_status ==2){
            $redirect_to = site_url('users/campaign/dashboard');
        //}else{
          //  $redirect_to = site_url('users/campaign/add');

        if($check_exists_user->stripe_active == 0){
                $this->email_template->send_mail('activation-request',$id);
            }
        exit(json_encode(array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Account Detected', 'redirect_to' => $redirect_to)));
    }else{
        exit(json_encode(array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'Sorry, no account found.')));
    }
}

public function login(){
    $this->title_for_layout = 'Login';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That code isnt helpful at all in understanding whats going on. How about doing an echo of the current user who is logged in and have two facebook accounts on you, first login with the first facebook account, and do an echo to see if your logged in then logout of the facebook account from your app, then do an echo again to see if anyone is logged in, then try the same thing with the other account. chances are the logout session isnt working correctly. i've had the same issue before. If you try this and it works correctly for you then the person who logged into your site using facebook had another account that was logged into from their computer.